# install and configure metacity on crunchbang

Tags: linux, ubuntu, window-manager, metacity, crunchbang

I am trying to get `metacity` to work on my `#!` installation, but instead when I try to run `metacity` at the command line, it tells me that there is another WM in process.

I then tried to run `metacity --replace` (as it suggested) but to no avail; it appears as though X quit.

What should I do? Or how can I get CrunchBang to otherwise look a bit more like Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I have experience metacity causing X to quit when I was running live session. When I've installed crunchbang, it worked perfectly fine (I was using xfce4 though):

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4 metacity metacity-themes
```

After then either logout, and select xfce4 for your session, or use:

```
xfce4-session
metacity --replace
```

You can then use xfce4 configurations to set different theme, - however to change metacity themes, you'll have to install gconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install gconf-editor
```

Run it:

```
gconf-editor
```

And go to `apps/metacity/`, and change the theme name.

You can find metacity themes here: http://gnome-look.org/index.php?xcontentmode=101

After downloading it, put it to the `~./themes` directory.

Comment: Basically it kicked me back to the GDM. ;)